# Append and call dynamic javascript function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Can you create a dynamic javascript function and immediately call it?

I already found that you can't use the callback from append.

proposed, non working, code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".main").append('
       <script type="text/javascript">function init'+count+'(){alert("'+count+'");}<'+'/script>
    ');
    window['init'+count]();
});
</script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

### Edit:

Narrowed it down to a synchronization problem. Placing `alert("")` between append and window makes it work, but that is not really a useful fix because the count might go up to a 100 when I place this code in a loop.
Guess I'll have to keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, but you aren't quoting correctly. There shouldn't be any unescaped double quotes within `append("` and `")`. Try:

```
$(".main").append("
       <script type=\"text/javascript\">function init'+count+'(){alert(\"'+count+'\");}<'+'/script>"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

use an external script and `$.getScript()`, it allows you to specify a callback and makes your code a bit neater

```
$.getScript("http://scriptURL.com/script.js", function(){ itit(); });
```

Theres no point of inlining the code.. you could just run it in the same place you're appending the tags or use `jQuery.globalEval();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! This is the way javascript was invented! It is extremely powerful:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=1;
var init = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function (count) {
        init[count] = function () {
            alert(count);
        }
    })(count);
    init[count]();
});
</script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

or, if you just want to construct and call the function without storing it ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function () {
        alert(count);
    })();
});
</script>
<div class="main"></div>
```