# inject GA4 script in the html of a static site with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection, static-site

I have the following situation:

- a static site, only html pages
- a cookie notice system, with my own cookies, accept and refuse system of cookies setup

Now I need to inject the GA4 script into the head of pages when cookies are accepted, but...

I have already made made that, by appending the script to the head and it is visible on browser, on page reload with inspect elements...and it's working perfect.

When users click on accept cookies, the cookies accept is saved on client's side, and the script is APPENDED to page.

But I need the GA4 script to be somehow INJECTED, to be visible on the source page. Like when I preview the source page in browser to have it there. I don't need it to be injected into the html file itself, but only into the browser.

I did my own research about these days, and now it's killing me, as all I could find was the append way, but that is not injecting it into the source page on browser.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Note (as I have been asking all the time. I don't want to offend anyone, but that's the best way I can explain where I want to do and what):

- the source page I'm talking about is when right click on browser and view source page (there is where I need the GA4 code to be inserted)
- and the way I got it to work is when right click > inspect > elements tab - (there i have it now working)

Thank you!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for. I *think* you're looking for `eval()` (which is unsafe and shouldn't be used in production) or `const script = document.createElement("script"); script.src="link_to_script";document.appendChild(script);` . Is it your own website? What have you tried?

Comment: :)) and I tried to be very clear. I appended my google adsense (GA4), to page with document.appendChild(script), like you mentioned. And when I do on webpage Inspect > Elements I can see my script right before the </head> tag, where it should be.

Comment: but when I do View Page Source on the same page form browser, I can't see that google adsesnse script anymore. ..and that's the place where I want to have it.. in the source page on browser. Is that posible? ... IDK how to explain better..with my appologies

Comment: script tags should preferably be at the bottom of the `body` tag. Yeah, i'm not sure what you mean so it's hard to help you. GL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run script after appending it to the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178848/run-script-after-appending-it-to-the-html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First question would be, why do you want it to be in the actual source code? A common way of inserting these scripts is through a tag-management-solution, which basically follows similar logic as appending scripts to the page (i.e. similar to what you meant by the inspect elements route).

To answer your question;
There is an option to get it into the sourcecode, and that is by checking on the server delivering the HTML whether a user has accepted the cookies, if that is the case deliver the HTML file (or adjust the HTML) to contain the GA4 script, if the user didn't accept: deliver the page without the GA4 script.

Since you mention these are static HTML files, I assume there is no server in place where this kind of logic can be inserted. So the best option is to insert the script afterwards.

Another way would be to insert the tag by default, but disable tracking (haven't tested the below part, also, verify yourself whether in your situation this actually blocks tracking when cookies aren't accepted):

```
window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/user-opt-out

You could try to add this in your HTML before loading the GA4 tag, similar to something like:

```
<script>
const gaMeasurementId = 'G-12345678'; //replace with your own MeasurementID   

let cookiesDeclined = true; //default to declined cookies
document.cookie.split(';').forEach( (cookie) =>{ //loop through all cookies
    const cookie_arr = cookie.split('='); //get key/value pairs for cookies
    let name = cookie_arr[0]; //cookiename
    let val = cookie_arr[1]; //cookieval

    if(name === 'cookieConsent' && val === 'accepted' ){
        cookiesDeclined = false; //set the declined status to false when user has accepted the cookies
    }
})

window['ga-disable-'+gaMeasurementId] = cookiesDeclined;

//->insert ga4 tag here
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Kernell, Thank you for your answer. Firts of all, to answer your question. I want the ga4 code to be in source code, bcause I'm not sure if that will work the same when it's just appended.

Comment: and second thank you for your solutions. I think I'll try to insert the code and see if traking is disabled when users do not accept cookies. Thank you again!

Comment: It works basically the same when it's appended. That is how many GA(4) implementations work in production (mostly through e.g. Google Tag Manager). Main difference is in 'when' it is being loaded.

Comment: Hi again Kernel... I appologize for being rude with my questions.. but can you give an example of difference on "when" it is being loaded? For example I'm loading the GA4 tag (appended to the source page), only and only after I get te approval from the user, and it's removing itself automatically when the cookie expired or user removed the cookies form browser. Is that the difference you were meaning about "when"it is loaded?  Thank you and apologies again

Comment: When the code to execute is in the source code, it will be executed when the browser reaches that code. When appending, there are more steps, so there might be a bit of a delay. When appending the browser first needs to reach the code where it is appendend, then append the code and then execute it. I think in most cases this has small impact (milliseconds) though.